# Display plymouth on Ubuntu server 18.04

Tags: boot, grub2, plymouth

I installed Ubuntu Server 18.04 and Budgie desktop on top as my desktop environment. I don't want to see the text running when I restart or shutdown.

I found out that in `/boot/grub/grub.cnf` I have:

```
quiet splash $vt_handoff
```

It works but after updating Grub it goes back to the default.

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the compiled file rather than the source file. When `sudo update-grub` runs your changes to the compiled file are replaced by the source file.

The correct source file to edit is `/etc/default/grub`.

After saving `/etc/default/grub` changes then you need to run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: More a comment than an answer.

Comment: @A.B. Unless we can somehow close this question, it will keep popping up on the home page until it is answered. With your downvote this question may qualify to keep popping up on the home page from time to time because it doesn't have an upvoted answer. I'm not positive on this mind you... Still no matter how you look at it the answer must be correct. Also the user is unlikely ever to sign-on again to delete th question.